# Freeform Pro: Field Placeholder

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, solspace

is it possible to add placeholder text (i.e. placeholder="Your Name") in a Freeform Pro: Composer Form Field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you replace `{composer:field_output}` with `{freeform:field:{composer:field_name} attr:placeholder="Your Name"}` in the Composer Template.

If you're using the *Freeform channel custom field* (i.e. using the field in {exp:channel:entries}), you'll have to select your custom Composer Template (containing the above code) in the top left dropdown  of the Composer Editor in the Freeform Control Panel. That way, that Composer Template is used when calling the Freeform custom field in {exp:channel:entries}.